# where do i put the password_verify function in my code please?

Tags: php

I am working on a login form. I already did my registration form with password_hash function and successfully saving all passwords in this manner in my database.

i have no idea where i will put the passwod_verify function and what i must code the verify exactly in order to get the plain txt password be compared with the hashed version ?
i know that i need to break this problem into 2 parts:
1) fetch the hashedpassword from my database after username is checked.
2) compare this with the user input password to verify and allow the user to login.

my code is below and part of my database also.

![my database content][1]

```
  <?php require_once('Connections/bankusers.php'); ?>
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "")
{
if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
$theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
}
$theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);
switch ($theType) {
case "text":
$theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
break;
case "long":
case "int":
$theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
break;
case "double":
$theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
break;
case "date":
$theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
break;
case "defined":
$theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
break;
}
return $theValue;
}
}
?>
<?php
// *** Validate request to login to this site.
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
session_start();
}
$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
$_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
}
if (isset($_POST['UserName'])) {
$loginUsername=$_POST['UserName'];
$password=$_POST['Password:'];
$MM_fldUserAuthorization = "";
$MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "loginusermemo.php";
$MM_redirectLoginFailed = "loginuser.php";
$MM_redirecttoReferrer = false;
mysql_select_db($database_bankusers, $bankusers);
$LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT UserID, Password FROM users WHERE UserID=%s AND Password=%s",
GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "int"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text"));
$LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $bankusers) or die(mysql_error());
$loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);
if ($loginFoundUser) {
$loginStrGroup = "";
if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else {session_regenerate_id();}
//declare two session variables and assign them
$_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
$_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;
if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
$MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];
}
header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
}
else {
header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
}
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login User</title>
<meta name="description" content="website description" />
<meta name="keywords" content="website keywords, website keywords" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css" title="style" />
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryValidationTextField.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="SpryAssets/SpryValidationTextField.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
<div id="header">
<div id="logo">
<div id="logo_text">
<!-- class="logo_colour", allows you to change the colour of the text -->
<h1><a href="index.php">ModelOnline<span class="logo_colour">Bank</span></a></h1>
<h2>Your. Bank. On. Demand.</h2>
</div>
</div>
<div id="menubar">
<ul id="menu">
<!-- put class="selected" in the li tag for the selected page - to highlight which page you're on -->
<li class="selected"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="register.php">REGISTER</a></li>
<li><a href="login.php">lOGIN</a></li>
<li><a href="aboutus.php">ABOUT US</a></li>
<li><a href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a></li>
<li><a href="accessibility.php">Accessibility</a></li>
<li><a href="security.php">Security</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div> <div align="center" class="bankservices"><a href="http://www.modelonlinebank.com/bankproducts.php#one">Current Accounts</a> | <a href="http://www.modelonlinebank.com/bankproducts.php#two">Savings Accounts</a> | <a href="http://www.modelonlinebank.com/bankproducts.php#three">Mortgages</a> | <a href="http://www.modelonlinebank.com/bankproducts.php#four">Insurance</a> | <a href="http://www.modelonlinebank.com/bankproducts.php#five">Credit Cards</a> | <a href="http://www.modelonlinebank.com/bankproducts.php#six">Investments</a></div>
<div id="site_content">
<div class="sidebar">
<!-- insert your sidebar items here -->
<h3>Latest News</h3>
<h4>Personal Banking</h4>
<h5>January 1st, 2014</h5>
<p>Current Accounts,Saving Accounts,Range of Credit And Debit cards to suit all your needs. We have your interest in mind.<br />
<a href="#">Read more</a></p>
<p></p>
<h4>Corporate Banking</h4>
<h5>February 5th, 2014</h5>
<p>We help you achieve your goals by providing numerous funding options.Provide Risk management of your finances and look for strategic and finance options to promote business.<br /><a href="#">Read more</a></p>
<h3>Useful Links</h3>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Credit card</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Debit card</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Loans</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Insurance</a></li>
</ul>
<h3>Search</h3>
<form method="post" action="#" id="search_form">
<p>
<input class="search" type="text" name="search_field" value="Enter keywords....." />
<input name="search" type="image" style="border: 0; margin: 0 0 -9px 5px;" src="style/search.png" alt="Search" title="Search" />
</p>
</form>
</div>
<div id="content">
<!-- insert the page content here -->
<h1>Login Part 1 of 2</h1>
<p>Please kindly Input your Account Number and Password below:</p>
<form action="<?php echo $loginFormAction; ?>" method="POST" name="loginform" id="loginform">
<table width="500" border="0">
<tr>
<td><span id="sprytextfield1">
<label for="UserName"></label>
Account Number: <br>
<input type="text" name="UserName" id="UserName">
<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Enter Your Account Number.</span></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span id="sprytextfield2">
<label for="Password:"></label>
Password: <br>
<input type="password" name="Password:" id="Password:">
<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Enter Your Password.</span></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="LoginButton" id="LoginButton" value="Login"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="content_footer"></div>
<div id="footer">
&copy;Modelonlinebank 2014 | <a href="#sitemap">SiteMaP</a> | <a href="#privacy">Privacy</a> | <a href="#jobs">Jobs</a> | <a href="#terms">Terms</a> | <a href="contactus.php">Feedback</a></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var sprytextfield1 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield1");
var sprytextfield2 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield2");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may seriously want to consider using a framework like [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter), [Laravel](http://laravel.com/), or [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) for this kind of website. It takes care of your database queries, security, forms, password authentication, and much more.

Comment: You're building your code on the assumption that you want it to run on pretty much any version of PHP. you should NOT be facilitating the use of dead/ancient/obsolete PHP versions. Especially since you're using an obsolete/deprecated database interface, so while you're bending over backwards for backwards compatibility, your forward compatibility is essentially zero.

Comment: `if (PHP_VERSION < 6)` wtf?!? Is anybody in the world running a version of PHP >= 6 yet?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to ignore the security of this form and just focus on what you are asking. You need to change

```
$password=$_POST['Password:'];
```

To this (assuming you are storing just the md5 hash in the database):

```
$password=md5($_POST['Password:']);
```

Comment: I am not using md5. Instead i am using password hash...in this format :

password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_DEFAULT)

Thanks Sergei for ur input and others for pointing security issues (please do not worry about PDO or MySQli for now , just focus on this issue ).

My problem is how to compare this saved password in my login process using the function below:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php